# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string

Tags: php

I have this error. I don't know why. My error is in line 348, (`in_array`). I have PHP 8, is it for that? `in_array` doesn't works. I don't see the error. When I replace `$key` for 1, it works but the variables don't.

This is my consult SQL:

```
$sql="SELECT venta, sucursal, r.`rubro`, fecha
        FROM ventasiniva
        JOIN rubros r USING (idrubro)
        WHERE DATE(fecha) BETWEEN '$desde' AND '$hasta' ";

    if(strlen($idsucursal)>0){
        $sql.=" AND idsucursal in (".$idsucursal.") ";
    }
    if(strlen($idrubro)>0){
        $sql.=" AND r.idrubro in (".$idrubro.") ";
    }

    $respuesta=ConsultaAsociado($sql);

    $resultado['id']=$respuesta['id'];
    $resultado['mensaje']=$respuesta['mensaje'];
    $resultado['cantidad']=$respuesta['cantidad'];
    $resultado['datos']=columnaunico($respuesta, 'sucursal');
    // $agrupado=agrupararray($respuesta,'fecha');
    // $resultado['datoslineal']=arraylineal($agrupado,'fecha','sucursal','venta');

    if(strlen($error)>0){
        $resultado=array("id" => 0, 'mensaje'=>$error);
    }
    echo json_encode($resultado);
```

This is my function:

```
function columnaunico($array, $key) {
    $temp_array = array();
    $i = 0;
    $key_array = array();
   
    foreach($array as $val) {
        if (!in_array($val[$key], $key_array)) {
            $key_array[$i] = $val[$key];
            $temp_array[$i] =  str_replace(" ", "_", $val);
        }
        $i++;
    }
    return array_column($temp_array, $key);
}
```

[image]

Comment: You're using PHP 8 and yet still you have basic SQL injection problems... Use PDO for your database queries!

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Comment: The SQL part doesn’t actually clarify much. Please show us what your $array variable actually contains in your function.

Comment: So obviously `$val` is a string and not an array as you expect it to be. Dump the `$array` to find out where you're going wrong.

Comment: If you want to ckeck keys, use `array_key_exists` insteed `in_array`

Comment: use `print_r($val)` after  `foreach($array as $val) {` to see if $val is itself array or not.

Comment: Perhaps you need to use `foreach($array as $key=>$val) {`